# Reactjs: beforeunload doesn't get triggered as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call a function every time I refresh the page. I'm doing the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchData(this.state.data);
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleRefresh);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleRefresh);
}
```

And the function I'm trying to call is the following:

```
  handleRefresh = () => {
    // refreshPage here is an action method that talks to the backend
    this.props.refreshPage(this.props.some_data)
  }
```

The issue here is, the first couple of times I refresh the page, I get the expected output on the backend. After a couple of times, refreshing the page doesn't seem to trigger the backend method at all. Is this the correct way to trigger and get access to the refresh event?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an event listener? React provides "lifecycle methods" that fire during specific stages of a page's life.  If you want to call a function every time you refresh the page, just put the function inside `componentDidMount` or the class constructor. Those are executed whenever the page is loaded. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.refreshPage(this.props.some_data);
}
```

What is the purpose of `fetchData`? You seem to be running the function but not doing anything with its return value.

Comment: As I said at the beginning of my question, I want to execute a specific function (the `handleRefresh`) function on my code above, when the user clicks the refresh button. And to answer your question about the `fetchData` method, it is responsible for fetching data from the backend and rendering them on the frontend. I know the general purpose of lifecycle methods, but `componendDidMount` in this case isn't really serving my purpose of handling the refresh even in particular.